# export R code results in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r

I want to execute R code blocks in `org-mode` and export the *results* to a PDF/html.

Here is an example:

```
Some text here...

#+begin_src R :results output latex
library(xtable)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x + rnorm(100)
xtable(summary(lm(y ~ x)))
#+end_src
```

I want to export the *results* (here, the output of `xtable(summary(lm(y ~ x)))`), but I can't figure out how to do it.  When I export it to LaTeX or html, the text and code is exported nicely, but no table is produced in the output pdf / html file. **This is the core problem I need help with. How do I get the *results* to export, and not just the code?**

I have tried several experiments but not sure what settings I need to change.

- If I execute the code inline (using `C-c C-c`), I am asked to allow for execution, and when allowed a beautiful LaTeX table is generated below the code as expected. Not sure why this is not happening when exporting to LaTeX or html.
- I know that code is executing: If I modify the switches as below and then export to LaTeX/html, an output file is produced with appropriate name, but no results are integrated into resultant LaTeX pdf or html file. The syntax coloring is still present.

  ```
  #+begin_src R :results output latex :session *myR* :dir "." :file r-output.org
  library(xtable)
  x <- rnorm(100)
  y <- x + rnorm(100)
  xtable(summary(lm(y ~ x)))
  #+end_src
  ```

Comment: I've tried to clarify what I think it is that you're trying to ask.  You can roll back the changes if I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: @Dan: Many thanks. This is certainly more readable. I'll try to keep these in mind in future. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the `:exports both` header argument. By default, org only exports R code, not the results. From the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Code-Blocks.html):

> ## 14.8.2.8 :exports
>
> The :exports header argument is to specify if that part of the Org file is exported to, say, HTML or LaTeX formats. Note that :exports affects only ‘src’ code blocks and not inline code.
>
> `code` The default. The body of code is included into the exported file.
> Example: :exports code.
>
> `results` The results of evaluation of the code is included in the exported file.
> Example: `:exports results`.
>
> `both` Both the code and results of evaluation are included in the exported file.
> Example: `:exports both`.
>
> `none` Neither the code nor the results of evaluation is included in the exported file. Whether the code is evaluated at all depends on other options.
> Example: `:exports none`.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the text output but does not export images.

Comment: You may need to add a `:results graphics` header argument for plots. See http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html#orgheadline4

Comment: Is there a way to export the output of a code block, but not the result?

Comment: @JonathanPeel `:results output`. See the manual: https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html

Comment: @tyler, you are awesome, thank you.

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to set :export both as the default?